# Google drive api to upload file not working

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

```
function listFiles(auth) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');

var fileMetadata = {
  name: 'My Report4'
  // mimeType: 'text/plain'
//  'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'text/plain',
  body: fs.createReadStream('photo4.txt')
};
service.files.create({
  auth: auth,
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'

}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id:', file.id);
  }
});
}
```

> error :{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' } .

I think the problem is in body: `fs.createReadStream('photo4.txt');`

If i change it to `body : 'ANy text'` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, your script works fine. For example, how about trying the following modified script?

```
var service = google.drive('v3');
fs.readFile('photo4.txt', function(err, content){
    var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'My Report4',
    };
    var media = {
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        body: new Buffer(content, 'binary'),
    };
    service.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        auth: auth,
        fields: 'id',
    }, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
        }
    });
});
```

If this was not useful for your environment, I'm sorry.